# Covariant and controvariant bases derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation

How to show that

$\overrightarrow{\textbf{e}}_\sigma\cdot\partial_\mu \overrightarrow{\textbf{e}}_\nu = \overrightarrow{\textbf{e}}_\sigma\cdot\partial^\mu \overrightarrow{\textbf{e}^\nu}$

where $\overrightarrow{\textbf{e}}_\nu$ and $\overrightarrow{\textbf{e}^\nu}$ are the the basis and dual basis vector of some manifold?

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe look for a counter example. I do not think this is true, indices on left and right differ, so usually there is a chart such that the numerical values are different too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you find this claim?  The first expression ${\bf e}_\sigma\cdot \partial_\mu{\bf e}_\nu$ is not covaraint. If one wrote instead   ${\bf e}_\sigma\cdot \nabla_\mu{\bf e}_\nu$ then it makes sense because  the Christoffel symbol is defined by
$$
\nabla_\mu {\bf e}_\nu = {\bf e}_\tau {\Gamma^\tau}_{\nu\mu}
$$
giving

$$
{\bf e}_\sigma\cdot \nabla_\mu{\bf e}_\nu= g_{\sigma\alpha} {\Gamma^\alpha}_{\nu\mu}
$$
and with $\nabla^\mu = g^{\mu\alpha}\nabla_\alpha $ and with the action of the covariant derivative on a covector being $\nabla_\alpha {\bf e}^\nu= - {\bf e}^{\tau}{\Gamma^\nu}_{\tau\mu}$ we get
$$
{\bf e}_\sigma\cdot \nabla^\mu{\bf e}^\nu = {\bf e}_\sigma (- {\bf e}^{\tau}){\Gamma^\nu}_{\tau\beta}g^{\beta\mu}=-{ \Gamma^\nu}_{\sigma
\beta}g^{\beta\mu}.
$$
So they differ by at least  minus sign.

(sorry that I keep editing -- I keep making silly errors)